# How to remove droplets from image using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to remove the droplets and holes from the image using only openCV.

Before `remove_small_objects`:

[image: Before remove_small_objects]

I have tried using `remove_small_objects`:

```
retval, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(output_im)

cleaned = morphology.remove_small_objects(labels, 1000)
cleaned = cleaned.astype(np.uint8)
labels = (labels * 255).astype(np.uint8)

retval_cl, labels_cl, stats_cl, centroids_cl = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(cleaned)
```

After `remove_small_objects`:

[image: After remove_small_objects]

For guidance, I should end up with an image like this
[image: Result wanted]

Comment: Looks like connected components also gives you a way to find the contours.  https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html.  Look at findContours.  Basically you need to filter your connected components or found contours to get only those that are below your threshold, and then draw those contours filled with your mask color.  Alternatively, find only those contours larger than your threshold and draw them to a new image.

Comment: without the source image, your problem is not reproducible. [mre] -- `output_im` is never shown. it must be a mask. if it's not a mask but the data you show in your first plot, there will be ***one*** connected component containing all pixels (assuming your picture isn't 0 anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

I have not taken a tested

Does this help?

Snippet:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology

image = cv2.imread('s.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

retval, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image)

# Remove small objects
cleaned = morphology.remove_small_objects(labels, min_size=1000)
cleaned = cleaned.astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite('cleaned_image.jpg', cleaned)
```